# URL Redirection - DotNetNuke

Tags: iis-7.5, dotnetnuke

I'm trying to redirect the following URL:

```
http://test.mydomain.com/Newsletters/BreakingNews/tabid/909/ctl/Details/mid/2574/ItemID/123/Default.aspx
```

to this one:

```
http://test.mydomain.com/Home/tabid/756/ctl/Details/mid/2572/ItemID/123/Default.aspx
```

This should happen to all the pages based on those parameters. The variable is the 123 before the Default.aspx.

Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using DNN7, you might be able to redirect all the requests to the Newsletters/BreakingNews tab (ID 909) to (ID 756) using the built in redirection.

Redirect the BreakingNews page to the Home page by modifying the Page Settings for the BreakingNews page to point to the Home page.

Comment: Hi Chris, we are using DNN 6.2.9

Comment: You might still be able to make what I suggested work in 6.2.9